# How to make 4 physical monitors appear as ONE large display?

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

first time and question here.

I have 4 TVs (Sharp 49UI7352E 49" 4K) which I want to make them behave as ONE large display, so that when I maximize a window and more importantly when I view a VBox host in FULL SCREEN mode, it will take up ALL the resolution of 3840x2160.

The TVs are configured in the Displays menu to run in 1920x1080 resolution and in a 2x2 formation.

Physically they are set up in 2x2 formation and the 2 upper TVs are upside down.

They are connected to the PC (UBUNTU 19.04) through a NVIDIA 1050 Ti on 3x HDMI and 1x DVI slots.

How to make them behave as ONE large display. Through the NVIDIA X server settings?

Tried using GNOME's Preferences | Monitor to un-check "Same Image in all Monitors", then drag-and-drop monitor 2 to the right of monitor 1, monitor 3 above monitor 1, and monitor 4 above monitor 2. Selected monitor 3 and clicked on Rotation to flip it upside down; repeat with monitor 4. This put four images on one monitor; I want the four monitors to emulate one desktop.

Also tried to enable [xinerama](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo) which failed; tried to enable it in the nvidia x config file, but could not save it.

Comment: Drag edges of window until it occupies all 4 screens?

Comment: https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/MultiMonitorDesktop/  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXRandR aptitude install arandr and https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/ may be useful reads.